# Redirection rule WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I need to create a **redirection rule in WordPress** .htaccess that will do this.

http://www.domain.com/blog/2017/article-slug -->

http://blog.domain.com/article-slug

So basically **removing the year and going from sub-directory to sub-domain**. 
I need to do that for more than 500 articles. So the option of doing this one by one is not very viable.

Thanks so much

Comment: Is Blog is custom post type ? also what is the permalink structure of now you are using ?

Comment: blog is a sub-directory
The permalink im using now is
http://www.domain.com/blog/%year%/%postname%/